# Get Parameters used by ObjectDataSource in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I access the values passed after an update using the following asp.net controls:

- details view
- objectdatasource

Thanks.

Comment: after update or on click of update button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good article written on ObjectDataSource @ 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ObjectDataSourceInDepth.aspx

For your specific query look for the "Events" section of this article.